# Hibernate doesn't create table and throw exception

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I have a problem with my hibernate project.
When I try to start simple method the Hibernate throw exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at ...

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'botsender.users' doesn't exist
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
at ...
```

I've tried change my xml config but It didn't help.
Here's config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin12345</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/botSender</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping class="com.bot.entity.User"></mapping>  
    <mapping class="com.bot.entity.Role"></mapping>  
    <mapping class="com.bot.entity.Chanel"></mapping>  
    <mapping class="com.bot.entity.MessageToChanel"></mapping>  
    <mapping class="com.bot.entity.MessageToUser"></mapping>  
    <mapping class="com.bot.entity.Status"></mapping>  
</session-factory>
```

And simple test-method is:

```
public class App 
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateAnnotationUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    System.out.println("Session created");

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
     User user = new User();
     user.setFirthName("Igor");
     user.setLastName("Petrenko");
     user.setNickName("6ruceVVayne");
     user.setToken("somethink");
     user.setRole(Role.ADMINISTRATOR);
    session.save(user);

    tx.commit();
    System.out.println("User ID=" + user.getId());
}
}
```

I also tried to change "create" to "update". And change " org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" to "MySQL5InnoDBDialect". But I still get stuck on the same exception.

Comment: You should set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = creat` to build table. `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`

Comment: Already tried. Didn't help

Comment: Check you DB user permissions for create table.